# Macro to ensure all cells in a table row are filled in

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I have a table in Excel and I want to make sure that if a user fills in at least one cell in a row, that they must fill in all the other cells in the row as well.

I've tried to create VBA Code for it below. Basically, it is saying, that if any field in row 7 of my table has something filled in, then check if the first cell in the table has a blank. I will copy/paste the code so it checks if the other cells in the row are filled in as well.

When I try to run this, it says "Object Doesn't Support this Property or Method". Can someone help me please?

```
Sub blank()
If Range("H7:Q7").CountA >= 1 Then
    If Cells(7, 8).Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Condition Type cannot be blank"
'I will repeat for the other columns in the row as well. 
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INNrH.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea; here is the correct syntax:

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("H7:Q7")) > 0 Then
    MsgBox "something is there"
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code, please. A range does not have a method `CountA`. `CountA` function belongs to `Application.WorksheetFunction`:

```
Sub blank()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, rngEmpty As Range
 Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here your sheet
 If WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Range("H7:Q7")) >= 1 Then
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Range("H7:Q7")) <> sh.Range("H7:Q7").Cells.count Then
       Set rngEmpty = sh.Range("H7:Q7").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
       MsgBox "Condition Type cannot be blank!" & vbCrLf & _
              "Blank cell(s) in " & rngEmpty.address, vbInformation, _
              "No blank cells allowed"
    End If
 End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This is actually a much more efficient version of the code I was going to create. It won't tell the user which field is missing, but is much more simple!

Comment: If you need to 'tell' the empty cell(s) address, it is possible. I can adapt the code. I used `sh.Range("H7:Q7").Cells.count` to allow changing of the range size, without modifying the code...

Comment: @Hashmat Habibzadah: Adapted the code to also return the addresses of empty cells of the checked range...

Comment: @Hashmat Habibzadah: Did you test the adapted code? Does it do what you need?